# Quote in joomla search

Tags: search, joomla, double-quotes, quote

I was working with a joomla site and found that quotes are creating problem with search. Single quotes are printed back with three backslashes with zero result, and double quotes are simply chopped off and string before the beginning of the double quote are getting matched while returning a result.

Any help, tips here ? Anyone has found and solved this before ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occur because simple quote is noticed like an sql injection, if you change your 42 line in com_search

```
if (substr($searchword, 0, 1) == '"' && substr($searchword, -1) == '"')
```

with

```
if (substr($searchword, 0, 1) == '"' && substr($searchword, -1) == '"')||(substr($searchword, 0, 1) == "'" && substr($searchword, -1) == "'")
```

try it and tell me what it returns

Comment: Thanks Tarek. Could you please tell me which file you are speaking about, more specifically ? Thanks again.

Comment: I see what you mean now Tarek. But you are assuming that the quotes might be present at the beginning and end of string only, whereas quotes can be present anywhere, midway as well. For example, I can have a name `Pinus mugo 'Mughus'` or `Pinus mugo "Mughus"`

Comment: Solved it nonetheless, from the same controller.php, and simply str_replacing quotes with null, if quotes are present midway in the phrase.

Comment: Be careful doing that as you're leaving yourself open to sql injections!

Comment: How do I open myself to sql injections by removing quotes from string for a search? Any code example ?